# Gmaps: multi-colored Polygon or polygon with picture

Tags: google-maps, polygons

Well I read the documentations and I didn't find how to custom your own cover for the polygon.
So I'm asking if it is possible in the first place.
To make things clear I want to identify each land with the type of the cultivated fruit and it will be nice if I can do something better than ONE unique color for each polygon in my map.
Please note that I'm using the **Gmaps v3**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that multi colored polygon or polygon with picture is possible at the moment because as per the documentation the fillColor property of polygon options takes only hexadecimal colors (#FFFFFF) as an input.

```
   var polygon_options = {
     paths: poly,
     strokeColor: color,
     strokeOpacity: 0.7,
     strokeWeight: 2,
     fillColor: "ff0000",
     fillOpacity: 0.2,
   };
```